# How to connect to Google Cloud SQL with python's pymysql running as part of a dockerized container running in a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, pymysql

Currently I am accessing my Google Cloud SQL locally through a proxy, as in the following.

```
conn = pymysql.connect(unix_socket='cloudsql/'+project_name, user=user, password=password, db=db)
```

Now I have set up my cluster and whitelisted its External IP. I need to change the line above to connect to Cloud SQL from Kubernetes. (I don't think I can keep using the proxy, as it cannot be dockerized) I am unsure how to change my pymysql.connect() call.
Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an official [Cloud SQL proxy docker image](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine#proxy) that you can use as a sidecar container next to your app container, in the same pod. This is actually the recommended way to connect to Cloud SQL from GKE.

You'll find a detailed deployment configuration [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes-engine-samples/blob/master/cloudsql/mysql_wordpress_deployment.yaml) (this example is for wordpress but the idea is the same). Your app will use `127.0.0.1:3306` as the host address to access your database

Comment: Thank you! I’ll check it out

Comment: It worked. For a while I was also having a problem with setting the credentials as a secret, but it worked in the end